# Python: Moving items to a new list based on a counter value

Tags: python, list

I have a list of directories as strings. I'd like to iterate through the entire list and append each item into a new list, based on counting the item's file size, but increasing the outer list iteration each time a given threshold is reached by the counter.

```
output_list = [['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'],['file3.txt', 'file4.txt'],['file5.txt']]
```

I've tried a lot of different approaches but haven't been able to return to the top of the first loop once the counter reaches the threshold.
I've been using a while loop embedded in a for loop. I understand the code sample before will exit once the counter reach x, I'm just having trouble with returning to the top of the for loop, or "reseting" the counter.

```
import os

counter = 0
item_list = []
for i in list:
    while counter < x:
        item_list.append(i)
        counter += os.path.getsize(i)

return item_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question (I don't have enough reputation to comment yet so I have to answer).  If I understand correctly, maybe this will do it:

```
counter = 0
item_list = []
for i in list:
    item_list.append(i)
    counter += os.path.getsize(i)
    if counter > x:
        break # gets out of the for loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean add item one by one as string into item_list? I think you may misunderstand the function **append of list(python built-in)**.

e.g.

```
a = [1,2]
b = []
b.append(a) will be b = [[1,2]] not b = [1,2]
```

so you counter will add by one every time. Hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're doing:

```
import os

output_list = [['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'],['file3.txt', 'file4.txt'],['file5.txt']]
counter = 0
item_list = []
for l in list:
    # At this point variable l is a list, containing strings
    while counter < x: 
        # Append a list containing strings (not strings like we want)
        item_list.append(l)
        counter += os.path.getsize(l)

return item_list
```

This is what you want to do:

```
import os

def file_stuff(output_list):
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    item_list = []

    # go through each list
    for files in output_list:
        # files = a list of strings
        while i < len(files) or counter <= x:
            # go through all the files
            # or until the counter is too large

            item_list.append(files[i])
            counter += os.path.getsize(files[i])
            i += 1

        # reset counter variable after each sublist
        counter = 0
        i = 0

    return item_list

output_list = [['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'], ['file3.txt', 'file4.txt'],['file5.txt']]

print file_stuff(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just change that code you have in your question to:

```
import os

counter = 0
item_list = []
for i in list:
    while counter < x:
        item_list.append(i)
        counter += os.path.getsize(i)
    counter=0
return item_list
```

Putting the counter=0 after the while loop in the for loop will move to the next value in your item list and then continue with whatever operation you are doing.

It's a bit hard to understand what exactly you mean but I'm pretty sure this should help.